# model of the databind listbox <Listbox vZsTu> must be an instanceof of org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.BindingListModel

Tags: java, spring-boot, mvvm, zk, selecteditem

I have this error:

> model of the databind listbox  must be an instanceof of
>   org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.BindingListModel.[us.protec.mrp_repository.model.NewJobOrder@76bdae15,
>   us.protec.mrp_repository.model.NewJobOrder@443ffb5a]

in my code:

```
<div class="row">
<listbox model="@bind(vmo.listJobOrders)" 
         onDoubleClick="@command('cerrarModal') @global-command('SeleccionarJobOrder', newJobOrder=vmo.jobOrderSelected)"
         selectedItem="@bind(vmo.jobOrderSelected)"
         mold="paging"  pageSize="6" emptyMessage="Empty">
         <listhead>
            <listheader label="Order" width="20%" />
            <listheader label="Costumer" width="20%" />
            <listheader label="Supplier" width="20%" />
            <listheader label="Description" width="50%" />
         </listhead>
         <template name="model"  var="item">
            <listitem><listcell label="@bind(item.order)"></listcell>
                      <listcell label="@bind(item.customer)"></listcell>
                      <listcell label="@bind(item.supplier)"></listcell>
                      <listcell label="@bind(each.description)"></listcell>
            </listitem>
         </template>
</listbox>
</div>
```

if i delete the `selectedItem="@bind(vmo.jobOrderSelected)"`

the code works.

in the modelView i have:

```
listJobOrders = new ArrayList<>();
jobOrderSelected = new NewJobOrder();
```

with getters and setters.

i need some help. Please.

Comment: The code works for me. Which version of zk are you using? As a guess, I'd recommend using `ListModelList` instead of `ArrayList` for `listJobOrders`, maybe that helps.

Comment: Im using ZK 8.5.0 with Spring boot 1.5.9, maven download all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have this line of code instantiated in your zul.

```
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit"?>
```

For some reason this line does not allow linking one object within another.

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use this below code it will work :**

```
public ListModel<NewJobOrder> getListJobOrdersM() {
        if (listJobOrdersMolelList== null) {
            listJobOrdersMolelList= new ListModelList<NewJobOrder>(listJobOrders);
        }
        return listJobOrdersMolelList;
    }
```